# CUDA Where To Declare Constant For Shared Memory Allocation

Tags: cuda, constants, declaration, gpu-shared-memory

I am running a fitness function for 1024 matrices, each matrix gets its own block and is the same size.  Each block has `n*n` threads (the dimension of the matrix) and needs to have `n*n` shared memory so that I can do an easy sum reduction.  However, the dimension `n` for all the matrices is variable before runtime (ie. it can be manually changed, though always a power of 2 so the summation is simple).  The problem here is that shared memory must be allocated using a constant, but I also need the value to pass to the kernel from the host.  Where do I declare the dimension `n` so that it is visible to the CPU (for passing to the kernel) and can be used to declare the size of the shared memory (within the kernel)?

My code is structured like this:

from `main.cu` I call the kernel:

```
const int num_states = 1024
const int dimension = 4

fitness <<< num_states, dimension * dimension >>> (device_array_of_states, dimension, num_states, device_fitness_return);
```

and then in `kernel.cu` I have:

```
__global__ void fitness(
    int *numbers, 
    int dimension, 
    int num_states, 
    int *fitness_return) {
    __shared__ int fitness[16]; <<-- needs to be dimension * dimension
    //code
}
```

`numbers` is an array representing 1024 matrices, `dimension` is the row and column length, `num_states` is 1024, `fitness_return` is an array with length 1024 that holds the fitness value for each matrix.  In the kernel, the shared memory is hard coded with the square of `dimension` (so `dimension` is 4 in this example).

Where and how can I declare `dimension` so that it can be used to allocate shared memory as well as call the kernel, this way I only have to update `dimension` in one place?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Declare it at global scope, before you use it.

Comment: template parameters are your friend in this case

Answer (score 5):

The amount of allocated shared memory is uniform over all blocks. You might be *using* a different amount of shared memory in each block, but it's still all available. Also, the amount of shared memory is rather limited regardless, so n*n elements cannot exceed the [maximum amount of space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications) (typically 48KiB); for `float`-type elements (4 bytes each) that would mean n < 340 or so.

Now, there are two ways to allocate shared memory: Static and Dynamic.

**Static** allocation is what you gave as an example, which would not work:

```
__shared__ int fitness[16];
```

in these cases, the size must be known at compile-time (at *device-side code* compile time) - which is not the case for you.

With **Dynamic** shared memory allocation, you *don't* specify the size in the kernel code - you [leave it empty](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared) and prepend `extern`:

```
extern __shared__ int fitness[];
```

Instead, you specify the amount when launching the kernel, and the threads of the different blocks don't necessarily know what it is.

But in your case, the threads *do* need to know what n is. Well, just pass it as a kernel argument. So,

```
__global__ void fitness(
    int *numbers, 
    int dimension, 
    int num_states, 
    int *fitness_return,
    unsigned short fitness_matrix_order /* that's your n*/) 
{
    extern __shared__ int fitness[];
    /* ... etc ... */
}
```

nVIDIA's [Parallel-for-all](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/) blog has [a nice post](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/) with a more in-depth introduction to using shared memory, which specifically covers static and dynamic shared memory allocation.

Comment: I think maybe I mistated my question.  The value of n is the same across all blocks.

Comment: If I don't declare the size of the shared memory `fitness` I get the error `MSB3721`

Comment: @xjtc55: I'm not sure what that means, it looks like an MSVC error (which I don't use). Also, you haven't given a (minimal) program triggering this error - that would be a separate question, I think.

Comment: @ xjtc55: Can you retry? I've inserted a missing `extern` declaration.

Comment: @tera I had to rename the array (for some reason).  When I did that, the program ran, but it broke the algorithm.  I did a sanity check by making the array size twice the amount I needed (to show that the algorithm should work with just a pointer, despite size of memory allocation and indexing etc.)  It worked when the number was a constant.  Not sure the problem.

Comment: @tera it would then be possible to simplify use max_array_size (whatever that is) to allocate the memory, then no need to try any tricks.  This gets to einpoklums point that the full memory is there regardless, so it doesn't matter if I over allocate.

Comment: Keep in mind the third kernel launch argument is the size of th dynamically shared memory in bytes, not the number of elements. Also be aware there can only be one `extern __shared__` array per kernel (any additional dynamically sized shared memory array would get allocated to the same memory). For more specific advice you'd need to show the full actual code.

Comment: @tera: Oh, yes, sorry, I mis-copy-pasted. Thank you for the correction.